# Firebase: joining tables

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assume that the data look like this

```
post: {
  authorId: '123AA',
  title: 'first Post',
  body: 'yay'
}

author: {
  uid: '123AA',
  displayName: 'Richard'
  email: 'im@richard.com'
}
```

I want to render a post with the author's name:

```
<div className="post">
  <div className="title">{post.title}</div>
  <div className="body">{post.body}</div>
  <div className="author-name">{post.author.displayName}</div> //problem
</div>
```

A fetched post item only contains an author's `uid`, but I need the author's `displayName`. How do I populate the author field when retrieving the posts? This is what I do to fetch the posts right now:

```
const postsRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/')
postsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  this.setState({posts: snapshot.val()})
})
```

Comment: Its better to remove reactjs from the tags, the question has nothing to do with React

Comment: As far as I know you can't make "joins" with firebase, you need to make a second request to get something from another collection

Comment: so is that what people do? For every post that gets added, you make another request to get the user object from the server?

Comment: Check here a "join" example of firebase: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-join

Comment: @MaximusS a join indeed requires an extra call. These extra calls are not as expensive as most developers think, because [Firebase pipelines the requests over its existing connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807888/redux-firebase-data-sync

Answer (score 8):

Not sure in real firebase, but I use join quite often in angular2. Here my sample code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: `
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let p of posts | async">
            {{ p.title }} - {{ (p.authorName | async)?.displayName }}
        </li>        
    </ul>
`
})
export class InitComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.posts = this.af.database.list('/posts')
      .map(posts => {
          posts.map(p => {
              p.authorName = this.af.database.object('/authors/'+p.authorId);
          });
          return posts;
      });
  }
```

The database structure as follows:

```
/posts/postId/{authorId, title, body}
/authors/authorId/{displayName, email}
```

Hope this helps