# How to JOIN two nodes with AngularFire2 and Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have this structure of my Firebase Database

[image]

Each library can have several albums. How can I display the albums for each library?

the `albumsPerLib:` first element is the library key, and underneath each library key, I store the albums keys, that belong to it.

But I'm not used to NoSQL and can't figure how to join the *tables* to display the albums for each library.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire

Comment: that is angularjs not 2, and angularfire1 not 2. which i haven't dealt with. i think but not sure that the old ones didn't used observable?

Comment: Ah, that is indeed different. I think you'll have to use a `map()` call, but have only used that for synchronous operations myself.

Comment: I have answered joining tables in firebase here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789299/firebase-joining-tables/41090940#41090940

Answer (score 1):

so this works:

```
  getAlbumsThatBelongToLib(libKey:string):Observable<Album[]>{
//get the keys for the lib albums
const albumsPerLib$ = this.db.list(`albumsPerLib/${libKey}`);

//map the returned list of keys
//and get their details from the albums node
return albumsPerLib$
  .map((albumKeys) => albumKeys
      .map( (albumKey) => {
         return this.db.object(`albums/${albumKey.$key}`)
      }))
  .flatMap((res) => {
    return Observable.combineLatest(res);
  });
}
```